# MySQL CURDATE() function sometimes gives result, but sometimes doesn't show records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

[image]

This is the table in which I want to fetch records:

[image]

Flags are zero and the date is the current date, as you can see:

[image]

Still not showing records.

Sometimes it works, but mostly it is not working. Please guide me.

Comment: It could possibly be due to timezone setting - e.g. CURDATE is returning a date that is earlier than your expecting

Comment: Run this query `SELECT CURDATE()` to check.

Comment: It would be great if you could give us an example of your table using http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ for us to try some queries ourselves!

Comment: Are those `=`s or `-`s? Can you add the code to the question? You also don't need the `date` function since your column is already a `date`.

Comment: try after removing quotes from `'0'` in where condition.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem and the query looks fine. Did you check timezone?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the doc for [CURDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_curdate.asp)(), it looks like you're getting it back as a String value. Try the following query:

```
SELECT `id`, `receiver_phone`, `sms_content` FROM `sms_history` WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = DATE(CURDATE()) and `send_flag`=0 LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Those ' quotes should be ` quotes (other than the ones around 0, which shouldn't be there at all). This query will not work as is.

Comment: I think the quotes around the 0 would work regardless. Pretty sure it would convert it from a string literal to an integer anyways for the comparison. Either way I modified it based on the recommendations

Comment: You are right about the quotes around 0 as it would get cast appropriately. However you still have the wrong quotes in the rest of the query, it is the back-tick quote ` (below ~ on your keyboard), not single or double quotes.

Comment: Sir i have already tried this but still not working . i have also tried DATE(NOW()) but not working

Comment: And i have already tried 'CURDATE()' but not working  you  must know 'CURDATE()' retrun string like '2018-04-02' and without quotes it returen 20180401 but this is also  not working